# Identify records with duplicate values in a specified column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I am new to Python and Pandas.
I am cleansing a data file of 50,000 pieces of equipment (50,000 rows and 10 columns).
One column ('UNITNUMBER') should be unique for each record.  However there are duplicates and I'm trying to produce two data frames: one containing all the records where UNITNUMBER is unique and a second containing all the records where UNITNUMBER is repeated in another record.

The following produces a series where UNITNUMBER is the Index, True means duplicated, and False means unique.
`MData=pd.read_excel(MFile,MFileTab, skiprows=0)
DupSeries=(MData.UNITNUMBER.value_counts()>1)`

The following produces a series where there is one record for each piece of equipment in the same order as the original DataFrame, the index is the UNITMASTER values and the series value is True or False.

`DupSeries[MROData['UNITNUMBER']]`

I expected that

```
MData[DupSeries[MData['UNITNUMBER']]]
```

would yield all the records in MData where UNITNUMBER is duplicated but instead I get a warning and an error:

UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.

ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

In short, I can't figure out the syntax.  Please help.  I'm happy to use a completely different method if there is one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MDuplicates = MData.loc[MData.duplicated('UNITNUMBER', keep=False)]
MUnique = MData.drop_duplicates('UNITNUMBER', keep='first')
```

Comment: MData.loc[DupSeries] doesn't appear to work.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match

Comment: Note there are fewer records in DupSeries than MData because DupSeries has only one record for duplicate UNITNUMBERs whereas MData has multiple records for duplicate UNITNUMBER.

Comment: MDuplicates = MData.duplicated('UNITNUMBER', keep=False) doesn't work either.  It just returns a series indexed by incrementing integer (line number) indicating whether that record in MData has a duplicate UNTNUMBER.  I need all the columns from MData for each record that has a duplicated UNITNUMBER.